# com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error in Files list using query search

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to query a list of root files and folders which are owned by me and along with items which are shared with me.

So I am using this query - **((not 'me' in owners and sharedWithMe) or 'root' in parents)**

But, its throwing 500 interval server error.
**This error is only few user accounts, for others its working fine.**

Can someone help with this?

Versions

*google-api-client : 1.35.0*

*google-api-services-drive : v3-rev197-1.25.0*

Here is some log related to it -

`com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 500 Internal Server Error GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=user,allTeamDrives&fields=nextPageToken,%20files(mimeType,headRevisionId,createdTime,id,lastModifyingUser,modifiedTime,name,owners,ownedByMe,parents,permissions,shared,size,trashed,capabilities,webContentLink,teamDriveId)&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&orderBy=folder,name_natural&q=trashed%20%3D%20false%20and%20('me'%20in%20owners%20and%20'root'%20in%20parents)%20or%20(sharedWithMe)&supportsAllDrives=true at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:118) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:37) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:439) at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1111) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:525) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:466) at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:576)`

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question and include [example] this search method works fine in the [try me](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22q%22%3A%22((not%20%27me%27%20in%20owners%20and%20sharedWithMe)%20or%20%27root%27%20in%20parents)%22%7D) which leads me to  think this is an issue with your code.

Comment: 500s can mean a Google server error or [a quota issue](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/retry-strategy). As mentioned, try to share your code, but also, `not 'me' in owners and sharedWithMe` sounds redundant since `sharedWithMe` will already return only files not owned by you. Not sure if that could be a factor but I think a better `q` would be `sharedWithMe or "me" in owners`.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but I have tried "sharedWithMe or "me" in owners" as well.
It still throws the same error.